# Modulus in Java

Tags: java, modulus, conceptual

I want to get the value of an unknown number in equation containing modulus `%` in Java

For example:

`x % 26 = y` if I have the value of `y` how can I get `x`

Comment: Did you try to solve your problem ? Share your code attempt please.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that there are either zero solutions (if `Math.abs(y) >= 26`) or an infinite<sup>1</sup> number of values of `x` that satisfy that equation for a given `y`. The general answer is:

```
x = 26 * k + y
```

for any integer value of `k`. You can pick whatever `k` you want.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup> In practice, the range will be limited by the range of integer values you are using. If `x` and `y` are `int` values, then you are limited by `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. On the other hand, if they are `BigInteger` values, you don't have much in the way of range constraints.

<sup>2</sup> Actually, the signs of `x` and `y` must be the same in Java, so you only have half of infinity to pick from. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the value of x, that's how modulus works. You just know x = 26 * k + y where k is an integer.