# I do not understand modulos, I have a learning disability

Tags: java, math, modulo

So i'm trying to understand modulo and I have been struggling due to a small learning disorder I have. My question is how do you determine the remainder of a modulo equation. If 27%16=11 
how do you get the eleven is what I don't understand?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Comment: "modulus" means remainder.

Comment: same thing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modulus in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237319/modulus-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

If you have a % b = c, then c is the remainder when a is divided by b. That is, if you repeatedly subtract b from a until you can't subtract any more without making it negative, that resulting number will be c.

Alternately, if you know how the / operator works in most programming languages with integer division, if a % b = c, then c is the number such that ((a / b) * b) + c = a.

Comment: good answer, to summarise, mod is the remainder of a division of two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Modulus is the "remainder" operator.

Consider the division

```
27 / 16 = 1 r 11
```

`27` is divided by `16` evenly `1` time, and has a remainder (denoted by the `r`) of `11`. In the context of integer division then

```
27 / 16 = 1    <-- The integral number of times the right operand divides evenly into 
                   the left (the number left of the 'r' from above)

27 % 16 = 11   <-- The 'remainder' of the division of left value by the right
                   (the number right of the 'r' above)
```

Algebraically if `k = x % y`, then `x - k` is evenly divisible by `y`

Comment: This is a very low quality comment; you should add explanation to clarify what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

27 is (16 * 1) + **11**. The eleven here is the "remainder". This is how you get modulo

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how many times 16 goes in 27 (which is 1), then you simply decrease:

27 - (16 * 1) = 11

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps

1. Divide the numerator by denominator
2. If the remainder is greater than denominator {
                        than make remainder the new numerator and repeat steps 1, 2
                         }else{

   ```
                    remainder is the  result
                     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> 16 x  2 = 32  which is greater than 27.
>
> 16 x  1 = 16 which is less than 27 by 11.
>
> > 16 < 27 < 32
> >
> > Therefore 16 divides into 27 one time. Afterwards you have 27 - 16
> >     this is what is left over after dividing by 16 you have 27 - 16 = 11.
> >
> > 27/27 = 1  with no left over so there is no remainder so 27 % 27 = 0;
> >
> > 27 % 16 = 11 because 16 will not go evenly into 27 but has a left over
> >     of 11.

Please add any follow up comment or questions and I will be happy to explain further. I know these things can be tricky when you are first learning them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Let's do this in basic manner.

now I need to divide `27` by `16`, `27/16`. Now `1X16=16, 2X16=32`.Now  `27<32`, then by dividing `27/16` we can have a value between `1` and `2`. In other word there is a remaining part, `27 -1X16=11`.

In `java` if we want to take this remainder at once, we use `%(modulo division)`

then `27%16=11`

```
 27 / 16 = 1, remainder 11  In java 27%16=11
```

Answer (score 0):

When you divide one number by another you can do it in two ways in a language like Java.

If you use floating point numbers by doing `27.0 / 16.0` you get a number with whole and fractional parts, such as `1.6878` which is `1+11/16` where `11` is known as the remainder.

If you use integer numbers then you have to use two different operations to get the whole and fractional numbers. You can do `27 / 16` to get the whole number result `1`, and you can do `27 % 16` and get the remainder of `11`.

Comment: you can use mod on floats and doubles too.